# Unable to deploy App from VS Code to ABAP Repository

Tags: sapui5, sap-basis

I am unable to upload a SAPUI5 Application from VS CODE to ECC ABAP repository, getting error

> Request TR#NO is not a change request

[image]

Comment: Tags edited: although it's named "ABAP repository" and the app is internally stored in the BSP repository, it's related neither to ABAP nor to BSP languages.

Comment: Please don't post same text more than once. And do not ask us to do anything ASAP.